# The return types for the following stored procedures could not be detected

Tags: linq-to-sql

While drag-drop a stored procedure in dbml file I get this error:

> **Unknown Return Type**
>   The return types for the following stored procedures could not be detected. Set the return type for each stored procedure in the Properties window.

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 27):

This problem occurs whenever the designer cannot figure out the return type of the SP.
Same problem and solutions described [here](http://riteshkk2000.blogspot.com/2010/08/error-unknown-return-type-return-types.html)
How to get multiple result set of procedure using [LINQ to SQL](http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/ibhadelia/archive/2010/07/17/how-to-get-multiple-result-set-of-procedure-using-linq-to-sql.aspx)

Basically this is the solution from the link:

> Avoid using **#temp** Table in your stored procedure, instead of you can use Table type variable like below (**@TempTable**)
>
> Ex:
>
> ```
> DECLARE @TempTable TABLE
> (
>   AttributeID INT,
>   Value NVARCHAR(200)
> )
>
> INSERT INTO @TempTable Select * from Attribute
>
> OR
>
> --Execute SP and insert results into @TempTable
> INSERT INTO @TempTable Exec GetAttribute @Id
> ```
>
> You can do all operation which you was doing with #Temp table like
> Join, Insert, Select etc.

Comment: This blog post may disappear some day. Can you include the solutions in your answer? (Of course, retaining the original attribution.) Thanks!

Comment: The Blog Post states basically is: Convert #TempTables to @TableVariables. I did this and this resolved the issue. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Post the solution to the answer here - replacing temp table with table variables is working solution for me.

Comment: Thanks for the giving reference , save my time :)

Answer (score 22):

Add these lines right after parameters declaration

```
AS
IF 1=0 BEGIN
 SET FMTONLY OFF
END
```

After this, write **BEGIN** and start your procedure work .

Comment: that's crazy :) but works

Answer (score 16):

I was using a temp table in my SQL and was getting this error. I converted the temp table to table variables and that resolved my issue.

Comment: from this :
---------  
CREATE TABLE #tmptable(
[Start Time] DATE, 
[End Time] DATE
);
select * from @tmptable;
----------
to this:
----------
declare @tmptable table
(
[Start Time] DATE, 
[End Time] DATE
);
select * from @tmptable;
----------

Answer (score 15):

This can be also the problem of access rights. If the stored procedure doesn't have an access to the table you get the same error. I had a query selecting data from another database I didn't have rights for (in fact the account running the Visual Studio connection didn't have the rights) and I received the same error. After adding proper rights everything went fine.

**Trying to execute the stored procedure inside VS2010 (by right clicking in Server Explorer and selecting "Execute") helped me to solve the problem.**

Comment: This was the issue in my case. I had a stored procedure that was accessing a table in another database. I had access while designing but I forgot my application runs as a restricted account who didn't have access.

Comment: The sql login with this problem didn't have owner role of the database. When assigned owner role to it, the problem went away.

Answer (score 9):

I've just added about 300 stored procs to my DBML and experienced many of the problems noted here and elsewhere.

Here is a summary of the causes & solutions for the error "The return types for the following stored procedures could not be detected", based on what I have personally experienced.  Note that the problems described below can occur in the SP that you are having the error with, or *any other SP that is being called from that SP directly or indirectly.*

- Concatenating integers with string using a '+' symbol.  *Use CAST() on the integers, or in SQL2012 or higher use the CONCAT() statement.*
- Referencing tables in other databases. *Apparently a permissions issue. I wasn't able to resolve this one.*
- Any direct or indirect call to XP_CMDSHELL.  *I wasn't able to resolve this one.*
- Any syntax error in direct or indirect calls to other stored procs.  *Fix the call to the SP.*
- Temp Tables.  *Replace the Temp Table with a Table Variable.*
- SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF is in use, but the table being edited has a Indexed View on it. *Change the set statement to SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON.*

Answer (score 8):

Reason: Your Stored Procedure will be returning a complex type. that is,  multiple results or uses a temp table.

Resolution

It entirely depends on what your Stored Procedure is doing. Useful links

1. http://odetocode.com/code/365.aspx
2. http://riteshkk2000.blogspot.com/2010/08/error-unknown-return-type-return-types.html

Comment: A cleaner answer would just say use a table variable in place of any temp tables in your stored procedure.  That was the fix for me.

Answer (score 7):

Just in case anyone else comes across this, I have just experienced it myself.

In my case, I was referencing a table in an insert statement that no longer existed in my schema.  A closer inspection of my code revealed I was inserting into a table called "Account" which was now called "tblAccount".  Visual Studio threw no errors on saving the sp, but I experienced the same error when trying to add the sp to the dbml file.

Hopefully this will help someone else out.

Answer (score 5):

I also had this problem - had to comment out code that was constructing a polygon:

```
declare
    @MapBounds geography
    ;

select
    @MapBounds = geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((' + 
        cast(@NorthEastLng as varchar) + ' ' + cast(@NorthEastLat as varchar) + ', ' +  
        cast(@SouthWestLng as varchar) + ' ' + cast(@NorthEastLat as varchar) + ', ' +  
        cast(@SouthWestLng as varchar) + ' ' + cast(@SouthWestLat as varchar) + ', ' +  
        cast(@NorthEastLng as varchar) + ' ' + cast(@SouthWestLat as varchar) + ', ' + 
        cast(@NorthEastLng as varchar) + ' ' + cast(@NorthEastLat as varchar) + 
        '))', 4326)
    ;
```

Once it was added to the dmbl, I un-commented out the code and it worked like a champ!

Answer (score 5):

I also had the problem (VS 2012, SQL Server 2008R2). In my case it was a combination of the `+` operator and various `CAST` statements in the code. I haven't found a way to replace them with something VisualStudio likes, but I have come up with a workaround:

**Workaround "Dummy SELECT"**:

- Create a dummy SELECT statement with all the fields you need to return. For example:

```
    select 'bla bla' as field1, 123123 as field2, 'asñfs' as field3
```

- Comment out your SP code and just leave the dummy SELECT in your SP.
- Add your SP in the O/R designer and save (it should do know without an error message)
- Restore your original SP (leave the dummy SELECT as a comment for future use)

Answer (score 3):

You might as well consider using CONCAT() method instead of '+' to concat a string. Since I wasn't using temp table and yet still encounter this problem. I found out that concating strings using '+' triggering this.

In my case, I was using this:

```
SET @errorMessage = CONCAT('Update (ID=', @pnID, ') failed. Name already exists.');
```

Instead of:

```
SET @errorMessage = 'Update (ID=' + @pnID + ') failed. Name already exists.';
```

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this issue while trying to add a stored procedure into a DBML (LINQ) file.

Doing some research I found that this usually happens when the stored procedure returns multiple results or uses a #temp table for it's final select.

The solution that worked for me was to create a new stored procedure that wrapped the results of the original stored procedure result, into a table variable with the same columns as the temp table.

My wrapper stored proc looked something like this:

```
DECLARE @NewPrograms TABLE (
    Campaign_Number int,
    Campaign_Display nvarchar(255)
)

INSERT INTO @NewPrograms
    EXEC [dbo].[Original_Stored_Proc_With_Temp_Table_Result] @Program_ID


Select * 
From @NewPrograms
```

Open up your DBML file, drag-and-drop in your new wrapper stored proc.

Comment: None of the other solutions worked for me, except for this one. I had a fairly complex SP with multiple WITH clauses and resulting temp table. Converting the temp table to a table variable did not work until I used the above technique with a wrapper SP. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the stored procedure runs without erroring. Just had this problem and I assumed the person who made the stored procedure had tested it and did not try it myself.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found ... I put a SELECT on top (IF) with conditions that are not correct and create a variable table with the result he wanted to exit and then "ELSE" put things right. The first part is only if you understand the process output I want. Look at my example

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SS_getSearchedProductsDetailsNew]
(
 @mk int,
 @md int,
 @yr int = 0,
 @caroption int = 0,
 @condition int = 0,
 @producttype int = 0 ,
 @option int = 0, 
 @coloroption int = 0
)
AS

declare @sql nvarchar(max)

Begin
  if  @mk = 0 and @md = 0 and @yr = 0
    begin
        Declare @TempTable2 TABLE(
            ProductID numeric(10),
            TypeName nvarchar(50),
            MakeID numeric(10),
            ModelID numeric(10),
            ConditionID numeric(10),
            CarOptionsID numeric(10),
            OptionsID numeric(10),
            ColorOptionsID numeric(10),
            Make nvarchar(50),
            Model nvarchar(50),
            YearID numeric(5),
            Color  nvarchar(50),
            ProductType nvarchar(50),
            CarOptionName nvarchar(50),
            OptionName nvarchar(50),
            ColorOptionName nvarchar(50),
            ConditionName nvarchar(50),
            Notes  nvarchar(500),
            Price money,
            cog money)

            select * from @TempTable2

    end 

   else
   begin


  select @sql = '
    declare @theNotes  nvarchar(500)
    declare @theMake numeric(10), @theModel numeric(10), @theYear numeric(10)
    declare @makeName nvarchar(50), @modelName nvarchar(50), @ID numeric(5)
    declare @theProductType nvarchar(50), @theTypeName nvarchar(50)
    declare @theColor nvarchar(50),@theProductID numeric(10)
    declare @theCondition numeric(10),@theCarOption numeric(10) , @theOption numeric(10), @theColorOption numeric(10)
    declare @theConditionName nvarchar(50),@theCarOptionName nvarchar(50), @theOptionName nvarchar(50),@theColorOptionName nvarchar(50)
    declare @thePrice money, @theCog money


    declare @HoldingTable table(
        ID numeric identity,
        ProductID numeric(10),
        MakeID numeric(10),
        ModelID numeric(10),
        ConditionID numeric(10),
        CarOptionsID numeric(10),
        OptionsID numeric(10),
        ColorOptionsID numeric(10),
        Make nvarchar(50),
        Model nvarchar(50),
        YearID numeric(5),
        Color  nvarchar(50),
        ProductType nvarchar(50),
        Notes  nvarchar(500),
        Price money,
        cog money);

        INSERT INTO @HoldingTable (ProductID,MakeID, ModelID , ConditionID, CarOptionsID,OptionsID,ColorOptionsID, Make ,Model,YearID,Color,    ProductType, Notes, Price, cog) 
        SELECT   
            ProductNumber as ProductID,
            tblProductsForSale.MakeID as MakeID,
            tblProductsForSale.ModelID as ModelID ,
            ConditionID,
            CarOptionsID,
            OptionsID,
            ColorOptionsID,
            tblVehicleMake.Make as Make ,
            tblVehicleModel.Model as Model,
            YearID,
            Color,
            ProductType, Notes,
            tblProductsForSale.ResalePrice as Price,
            tblProductsForSale.SellPrice as cog
                from    tblProductsForSale, tblVehicleMake, tblVehicleModel where 
                tblProductsForSale.MakeID = tblVehicleMake.MakeID and  
                tblProductsForSale.ModelID = tblVehicleModel.ModelID 
                and tblProductsForSale.ProductStatus=''available'' and tblProductsForSale.Custom=0'

        if(@mk > 0)
        begin       
            select @sql = @sql + ' and tblProductsForSale.MakeID = ' + convert(varchar, @mk)
        end
        if @md > 0
        Begin
            select @sql = @sql + ' and tblProductsForSale.ModelID = ' + convert(varchar, @md)
        End
        if @yr > 0
        begin
            select @sql = @sql + ' and tblProductsForSale.YearID = ' + convert(varchar, @yr)            
        end
        if @caroption > 0
        begin
            select @sql = @sql + ' and tblProductsForSale.CarOptionsID = ' + convert(varchar, @caroption)
        end 
        if @producttype > 0
        begin
            select @sql = @sql + ' and tblProductsForSale.ProductType = ''' + convert(varchar,@producttype)  + ''''
        end 
        if @option > 0
        begin
            select @sql = @sql + ' and tblProductsForSale.OptionsID = ' + convert(varchar, @option)
        end 
        if @coloroption > 0
        begin
            select @sql = @sql + ' and tblProductsForSale.ColorOptionsID = ' + convert(varchar, @coloroption)
        end     

        --select @sqlInsert = 'INSERT INTO @HoldingTable (ProductID,MakeID, ModelID , ConditionID, CarOptionsID,OptionsID,ColorOptionsID, Make ,Model,YearID,Color, ProductType, Price, cog) '
        --select @sqlExec = @sqlInsert + @sql


        --select * from @HoldingTable
        select @sql = @sql + 'Declare @TempTable2 TABLE(
            ProductID numeric(10),
            TypeName nvarchar(50),
            MakeID numeric(10),
            ModelID numeric(10),
            ConditionID numeric(10),
            CarOptionsID numeric(10),
            OptionsID numeric(10),
            ColorOptionsID numeric(10),
            Make nvarchar(50),
            Model nvarchar(50),
            YearID numeric(5),
            Color  nvarchar(50),
            ProductType nvarchar(50),
            CarOptionName nvarchar(50),
            OptionName nvarchar(50),
            ColorOptionName nvarchar(50),
            ConditionName nvarchar(50),
            Notes  nvarchar(500),
            Price money,
            cog money)

        WHILE Exists(Select * from @HoldingTable )
            begin
                Select @ID = ID FROM @HoldingTable 
                Select @theProductId = ProductID from @HoldingTable
                Select @theMake = MakeID  from @HoldingTable
                Select @theModel = ModelID  from @HoldingTable
                Select @theCondition = ConditionID  from @HoldingTable
                Select @theCarOption = CarOptionsID  from @HoldingTable
                Select @theOption = OptionsID  from @HoldingTable
                Select @theColorOption = ColorOptionsID  from @HoldingTable
                Select @theYear = YearID from @HoldingTable
                Select @theColor = Color from @HoldingTable
                Select @theProductType = ProductType from @HoldingTable
                Select @theTypeName = TypeName from tblProductType WHere ProductTypeID = cast (@theProductType as numeric(10))

                Select @thePrice = Price from @HoldingTable
                Select @theCog = cog from @HoldingTable

                Select @theConditionName = ConditionName from tblConditions Where ConditionID = @theCondition
                Select @makeName = Make from tblVehicleMake Where MakeID = @theMake
                Select @modelName = Model from tblVehicleModel Where ModelID = @theModel
                Select @theCarOptionName = CarOptionsName from tblCarOptions Where CarOptionsID = @theCarOption
                Select @theOptionName = OptionsName from tblOptions Where OptionsID = @theOption
                Select @theColorOptionName = ColorOptionsName from tblColorOptions Where ColorOptionsID = @theColorOption

                Select @theNotes = Notes from @HoldingTable
                Select @theProductType = ProductType from @HoldingTable

                INSERT INTO @TempTable2  (ProductID,TypeName,MakeID,ModelID,ConditionID ,CarOptionsID,OptionsID ,ColorOptionsID ,Make , Model , YearID ,Color,   ProductType, CarOptionName ,OptionName,ColorOptionName ,ConditionName, Notes, Price, cog)
                VALUES (@theProductId,@theTypeName, @theMake, @theModel, @theCondition, @theCarOption,@theOption,@theColorOption, @makeName,@modelName, @theYear, @theColor,@theProductType, @theCarOptionName, @theOptionName, @theColorOptionName, @theConditionName, @theNotes,  @thePrice , @theCog )
                DELETE FROM @HoldingTable  Where ID = @ID
            end

            Select * from @TempTable2 order by ProductID '


            end
            exec ( @sql )

    End
```

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled a lot on this and came to conclusion, that if your stored procedure is dynamic and is combined with strings you sometimes miss something.. so while importing Visual Studio DBML import/update can not execute/test the procedure, so return type stays undefined, once you correct the procedure (query strings that you are building up to execute) you can add the procedure without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

**A simple way to solve this issue is** (December 2019)

- 1 Just making double # precede #tmp => ##tmp
- 2 Comment out DROP TABLE #tmp => --DROP TABLE #tmp
- Execute stored procedure and make sure that data showed up
- Drag stored procedure again and that's it, It will generate return type
- Last, Turn your store back to first situation and then save.

Hope I can help.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error too and finally I found out that I have changed a table field name and in procedure it did not change it yet, and so it showed an error when adding to *dbml*.
Now you can check this on your procedure and your table that fields are the same.

I hope this experience is useful.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I dragged and dropped the stored procedure, so I just followed what the error said:

> Unknown Return Type
> The return types for the following stored procedures could not be detected. Set the return  type for each stored procedure in the Properties window.

I selected the stored procedure and then selected properties tab, there there is a option called `ReturnType` which was empty and then hit the dropdown button on it and selected the table the SP was created and the issue is resolved.

If this doesn't help you can try any of the above answers.

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was that I had OPTION (RECOMPILE) set to get round a parameter sniffing issue. I temporary removed this while adding the SP and all worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You must place the

> SET NOCOUNT ON;
> SET FMTONLY OFF

at the top of the procedure . Like for example:

```
ALTER    PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Name]
  @your_params
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET FMTONLY OFF
    -- your other codes
End
```

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to drag this procedure over to the dbml in VS 2019 and I am getting this error - Stored Procedure Return Type Error The return types for the following stored procedures could not be detected.

I tried rewrite the Stored procedure but nothing goes well. Later I found that the table from where I created the Stored procedure will added some information like abc.tblname where abc is the name of the username. Liked in the example below.

**Problem : CREATE TABLE [abc].[tb_mobile](..

Solution : I just Converted this to dbo. Example - CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tb_mobile]( ..**

Now all my Stored procedure and the issue which I faced is totally resolved.

Hope this will work for you.