# How can I use a stored procedure that uses tables with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I can't seem to read this into Entity Framework and use LINQ because I get this error:

> The return types for the following stored procedures could not be detected. Set the return type for each stored procedure in the Properties window.

I tried googling but the solutions seem way out of my head.. any ways I can get around this?  desperate =[

The only way I can think of making this work is to create a new table.. but I can only use stored procedures unfortunately

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetGame_FantasyHome]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @GameDate varchar(8),
    @TricodeHome varchar(3)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE TABLE #FantasyHome(
        GameKey int,
        PlayerName varchar(50),
        Tricode varchar(3),
        StatString varchar(50),
        Position varchar(20),
        FantasyScore int
    )   

    DECLARE @gameKey int
    SET @gameKey = (SELECT GameKey FROM Games WHERE GameDate=@GameDate
        AND TricodeHome=@TricodeHome)

    INSERT #FantasyHome
    SELECT TOP 1 p.GameKey, p.PlayerName, p.Tricode, p.StatString, p.Position,
        (p.Yards/25 + p.Touchdowns * 6 - p.Interceptions * 2) AS FantasyScore
    FROM GamePassers AS p 
    WHERE p.GameKey=@gameKey AND p.Tricode=@TricodeHome
    ORDER BY FantasyScore DESC, p.Yards DESC

    SELECT *
    FROM #FantasyHome
    ORDER BY FantasyScore DESC

    DROP TABLE #FantasyHome
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> · The one way to get these types of stored procedures to work is to
>   edit DBML by hand or write your own method signature for the procedure
>   in a partial class To Handle multiple record set return from stored
>   procedure by LINQ see the link here.
>
> · The second way is to avoid using #temp Table in your stored
>   procedure, instead of you can use Table type variable like below
>   (@TempTable)

More info [here](http://riteshkk2000.blogspot.com/2010/08/error-unknown-return-type-return-types.html). Be sure to read also the [article about table variables in T-SQL](http://odetocode.com/articles/365.aspx) pointed in that blog post.

**EDIT:**
Check also answers to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7035669/1816426) for reference.

Comment: YOU'RE THE MAN!  turned it into table variables and it worked!!! you seriously seriously saved me hours of wasting time at work trying to find a solution

Comment: Next time remember to start looking for a solution by googling the error message or just a part of it and checking the results. ;)

Comment: i actually did.. i think my googling just sucks -.-