# LINQ Stored Procedure Result Issue

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, linq, visual-studio-2013

I have a VERY simple stored procedure.  In fact, it looks very similar to another one that WORKS just fine when dragging it from the server into the DBML. (Visual Studio 2013):

```
@intPuId integer
AS

SELECT TagName = CAST(ecv.value as VarChar(100)) FROM Event_Configuration ec
join Event_Configuration_Data ecd on ecd.EC_Id = ec.EC_Id and (ecd.Alias IN ('RUNTAG', 'A') or ED_Field_Id=2058)
join Event_Configuration_Values ecv on ecv.ECV_Id = ecd.ECV_Id
WHERE ET_Id=2 and ec.PU_Id=@intPuId
```

That's it. Pretty simple.  I don't see why it won't work and it is VERY frustrating.

***EDIT***

The error being thrown is:

> The return types for the following stored procedures could not be
>   detected. Set the return type for each stored procedure in the
>   Properties window.

***Second Edit***

I have no temp tables, so that resolution does nothing for me.  I am running this in a basic asp.net (aspx) solution (dropping the SP onto the dbml).  I think that answers all questions.

Comment: Is it throwing a specific error?  Or are you just not returning data?

Comment: I added the error above, sorry for that!

Comment: Why not show the whole code?

Comment: Read more here http://riteshkk2000.blogspot.com/2010/08/error-unknown-return-type-return-types.html?m=1 or this thats been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035669/the-return-types-for-the-following-stored-procedures-could-not-be-detected

Comment: I am showing the whole code.  The only thing I left out was the create statement for the SP and the few lines prior that are auto-generated by sql server.

Comment: I have also read the blog and the stackoverflow question before.  I have no temp tables in mine as you can see above and it should be clear that the result is  varchar.  When I try to set the output, it only offers int - but I need varchar, correct?

Comment: LINQ to SQL? Entity Framework? How are you attempting to access this stored proc?

Comment: Note above that it is Visual Studio 2013 and a dbml.  I have a server connection to SQL Server.  I drop the stored procedures onto the dbml and get this error.  It happens only on some of the SPs.  I access it through LINQ in vb.net after, but for those SPs that don't work I would have to build the code that LINQ automatically generates.  The problem with that is when I save the project, LINQ goes back and writes over all the code I injected to fix the problem.